# webview activity reloading once intent is completed

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I am having an issue of reloading of activity when intent is done.

I have one activity ShowHTM that uses webview. And one of the link in webview generates intent to send email. 
ShowHTM activity starts a spinner and once webview is loaded, the spinner is stopped.
On clicking the link on webview, it pops up the email client list. After choosing one, i send an e-mail. As soon as email is sent, the control returns back to ShowHTM activity and it starts showing the spinner again. Which I don't need. I want to control the exit code of the email intent. i.e. if intent is successful then exit the ShowHTM activity.

Any help on this?

Here is my ShowHTM activity:

```
public class ShowHTM extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.show_htm);
startSpinner("  Generating Preview...  ");
h_wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.h_wv);
h_wv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
startSpinner("  Generating Preview...  ");
h_wv.setInitialScale(24);
h_wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
h_wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
h_wv.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
h_wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
h_wv.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
h_wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
h_wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
h_wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
h_wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        h_wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(dl != null){
            dl.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        if(url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto",url.replaceFirst("mailto:", ""), null));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "User Comment:");
            emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
            return true;
            } 
        else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to `startActivityForResult` and implement `onActivityResult` - there is no guarantee that the resultCode in onActivityResult will be RESULT_OK when the email has been successfully sent (because you're relying on 3rd party applications), but it is a pretty good bet.

As for your other problem, you can try returning false in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` when the URL is mailto:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to save the state of your webview :

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    h_wv.saveState(outState);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.blah);
   if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
   } else {
       // inflate and display spinner
      startSpinner("  Generating Preview...  ");
      h_wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.h_wv);
      ...
   }
   // set settings & scale
}
```

If it's not working I suggest you to take a look at this solution :

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/

I think it's the same problem that rotation, you activity seems to be destroy but you can save the state of your webview.

Answer (score 0):

Try set boolean variable to true when you first run send mail. And check this variable is false before start your spinner any time.

p.s. what is 'dl'?